# Regex: using awk and sed to match websites by IP

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with multiple IP addresses for different websites, however I only want to print out the websites associated with a specific IP and display the website. For example,

```
128.125.21.1,/www.extra.com/home.html,2323,oiehfoioi,wopwpwp
124.15.21.1,/www.yahoo.com/9998,wjeoiwjo,bbdjksbk
```

All I need is the websites associated with 128.125.21.1 and I've gotten results using awk to print the entire web address and the IP but I would like to remove the IP
How can I combine awk and sed to accomplish this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. What you show aren't valid URLs, do you also want to remove the first `/`? Also clarify if what you want is to print the second comma-separated field on lines whose first comma-separated field is a specific IP. Finally, it would help if you show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you want can be stated as "print the 2nd comma-separated field from any lines whose first comma-separated field is `128.125.21.1`". If so, you can use:

```
awk -F, '$1=="128.125.21.1"{print $2}' file
```

On your example, that prints:

```
$ awk -F, '$1=="128.125.21.1"{print $2}' file
/www.extra.com/home.htm
```

Of course, that isn't an actual URL. To also remove the leading `/`, you can use:

```
$ awk -F, '$1=="128.125.21.1"{print $2}' file | sed 's#^/##'
www.extra.com/home.html
```